# Can not apply Service as "type: ClusterIP" in my GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I want to deploy my service as a ClusterIP but am not able to apply it for the given error message:

```
[xetra11@x11-work coopr-infrastructure]$ kubectl apply -f teamcity-deployment.yaml 
deployment.apps/teamcity unchanged
ingress.extensions/teamcity unchanged
The Service "teamcity" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP'
```

This here is my .yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: teamcity
  labels:
    app: teamcity
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: teamcity
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: teamcity
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: teamcity-server
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8111
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: teamcity
  labels:
    app: teamcity
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8111
    targetPort: 8111
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: teamcity
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: teamcity
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: teamcity
    servicePort: 8111
```

Comment: Did you just recently changed the service description from `NodePort` to `ClusterIP`? Maybe it's this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/221 ? Have you tried `kubectl replace` or `--force`?

Comment: Yeah that worked somehow. The Service now is of "type: ClusterIP" but there are no events in the ingress happening.

Comment: @yvesonline please for it as an answer. It has solved my question. Every followed problem is outside of the question scope

Comment: Glad this worked @xetra11 ! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply a configuration to the resource by filename:

```
kubectl apply -f [.yaml file] --force
```

This resource will be created if it doesn't exist yet. To use 'apply', always create the resource initially with either 'apply' or 'create --save-config'.

2) If the first one fails, you can force replace, delete and then re-create the resource:

```
kubectl replace -f grav-deployment.yml
```

This command is only used when grace-period=0. If true, immediately remove resources from API and bypass graceful deletion. Note that immediate deletion of some resources may result in inconsistency or data loss and requires confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

On GKE the ingress can only point to a service of type `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` you can see the error output of the ingress by running:

```
kubectl describe ingress teamcity
```

You can see an error, as per your yaml if you are using an nginx controller you have to use the service of type `NodePort`

Somo documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md#gce-gke

Comment: I am using nginx ingress / controller. Therefore it should work with that.

Comment: Besides, Ingress doesn't point to `LoadBalancer` service, but `NodePort` **only**. Since `LoadBalancer` already includes `NodePort`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just recently change the service description from `NodePort` to `ClusterIP`?

Then it might be this issue [github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/221](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/221).

You need to use `kubectl replace` or `kubectl apply --force`.